# Celery Argument Passed Incorrectly

Tags: python, django, celery

When I was trying to pass a string as an argument into my celery file, this error occurred:

```sh
celery.beat.SchedulingError: Couldn't apply scheduled task add-every-10-seconds: get_data() takes 1 positional argument but 138 were given
```

However, I can't quite figure out why this means -- I *passed in the argument as a string*, but somehow, Celery converts it into a char array or something.

```
|-- data
    |-- tasks.py
|-- nttracker
    |-- celery.py
|-- manage.py
```

**nttracker\celery.py**

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import

app = Celery('nttracker', broker='amqp://', backend='rpc://', include=['nttracker.tasks'])
app.autodiscover_tasks()

app.conf.update(
    timezone = "Asia/Taipei",
    result_backend = 'django-db',
    broker_url = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379',
    cache_backend = 'default',

    beat_schedule = {
        'test': {
            'task': 'data.tasks.get_data',
            'schedule': 10.0,
            'args': "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/crimsonpython24/8a42e1c7226b73d59dcb2447fa961caa/raw/57441c0912cf51695b113745052c4829459dec02/test.json"
        },
    }
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

**data\celery.py**

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import

import django
django.setup()

import requests
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

app = Celery()


@app.task
def get_data(url):
    r = requests.get(url=url)
    data = r.json()

    print(data)
```

Can anyone please help? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`args` should be an iterable that will be unpacked and each element passed as a positional argument to the task.

Passing just a string causes the entire string to be unpacked and each individual char passed as an argument. You should wrap the string in a tuple or list

```
beat_schedule = {
    'test': {
        'task': 'data.tasks.get_data',
        'schedule': 10.0,
        'args': ("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/crimsonpython24/8a42e1c7226b73d59dcb2447fa961caa/raw/57441c0912cf51695b113745052c4829459dec02/test.json", )
    },
}
```